# How to control where HTML files are being output in Vite in a multi-page app?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, vite, rollupjs

I'm building a [multi-page application in Vite](https://vitejs.dev/guide/build.html#multi-page-app), and I have the following directory structure:

```
vite.config.ts
src/views/index.html
src/views/about.html
src/views/...
src/index.tsx
```

and my HTML files are importing `src/index.tsx`.

I want to keep all of my HTML files `src/views`, but in that case they are being output to `dist/views/...`, Is there a way to output them to `dist` root, so `dist/index.html` etc. instead? Through `build.rollupOptions`, maybe?

I already tried setting `root` to `src/views`, but then Vite is unable to import `src/index.tsx`. I'm not even getting a build error, but runtime 404 error inside my app.

Comment: a minimally reproducible example on stackbliz will get you the answer faster

Comment: @TachibanaShin thanks. I'm not in a hurry, and I don't like adding links to demos that might not always be there (e.g. if I delete my StackBlitz account).